# 文字列を置換するだけのスクリプトが凄く遅い

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

B列11行目から21行まで、`（株）` を `株式会社` 表記に直すコードを組んだのですが、実行時間が異常に長いです （10分近くかかる）。

現在サーバー上の問題でも起きているのか、それとも下記のコードに無駄な点が多いのか、ご意見をお聞かせください。

```
function Change() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート'), true);
    let lastRow = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRowIndex();
    let targetBase = 11;
    for(let row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++){
        spreadsheet.getRange('B'+(targetBase+row)).setValue(spreadsheet.getRange('B'+row).getValue().replace("(株)","株式会社"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getValue`や`setValue`をループ内で使用するとプロセスコストが高くなってしまいます。

Ref
[Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/10/12/benchmark-reading-and-writing-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/)

この場合、シンプルな方法としてTextFinderを使用するのはいかがでしょうか。表示されているスクリプトを修正しますと、次のようになります。

```js
function Change() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート');
  sheet.getRange("B11:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("(株)").replaceAllWith("株式会社");
}
```

この修正では、"ペースト&作業用シート"シートのセル"B11:B"の`(株)`は、`株式会社`に置換されます。

#### 参考

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=ja#createtextfinderfindtext)

Comment: 参考URLまでいただいて、丁寧説明して頂きありがとうございます！